# Confidence Interval for a Seaborn Boxplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, boxplot, seaborn, confidence-interval

I see that I can set a specific confidence interval on a seaboard point plot https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html however, for the 'notch' attribute on the seaboard box plot there seems to be no flexibility for the user to Specify the CI. Is there a way to do this? What is the confidence level of the default seaborn box plot notch?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`seaborn` relies on `boxplot` provided by `matplotlib` - [see docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.box). The default is 95%, but [here's](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo3.html) an example how to customize.